# Mysql mass edit

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I use Wordpress. I mass changed wp_posts table using this:

`UPDATE wp_posts SET someField = REPLACE(someField,'term1','term2')`

My question is: How can I make similar changes, but from a specific date until first post.

Sorry if my english is not very well!

Comment: Add the proper `WHERE ` clause...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `WHERE` clause like so:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET someField = REPLACE(someField,'term1','term2')
WHERE post_date < '2013-01-01'
```

Where `'2013-01-01'` should be replaced with the date in question.  Note, this would change *all* records where the post date was *older* than Jan 1st, 2013.